# Separate an HTML document with headings into sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I separate in sections a document with headings?

Convert this

```
<h1>chapter 1</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>sit amet</p>
<h1>chapter 2</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>sit amet</p>
```

into this

```
<div class="chapter">
  <h1>chapter 1</h1>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="chapter">
  <h1>chapter 2</h1>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>sit amet</p>
</div>
```

I guess with jQuery this is easy, but I haven't figured how yet.

Comment: Will there always be 2 P tags after the H1 tag or is it n P tags after the H1 tag?

Comment: I guess my question is why can't you just section based on the `h1` tags, rather than wrapping them in `div`s?

Comment: I did it after a fair bit of work in pure JS for those curious: http://jsfiddle.net/Wya2H/2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('h1').each( function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h1').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="chapter">');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/YVF2w/

Comment: JQuery really can become a language unto itself sometimes.

Comment: jQuery is not right solution here. The server should send the correct HTML.

Comment: No one would disagree that the server *should* send the correct HTML, and that mucking around at the client is not architecturally sound. But he's given no details about what constraints he's facing, so this straight answer might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> I guess with jQuery this is easy, but I haven't figured how yet.

Don't do this with jQuery. Write this into your HTML, or use whatever view / template engine your using to write your HTML like this.

Also there is such a thing as `<section>` and `<header>` I would recommend using them (but since they are HTML5 you might need html5 shim).

Comment: Dunno why that got a -1, I think it's good advice. Such things are far better done on the server once rather than on every client. I'll give you the 1 back.

Comment: -2 :\ Seriously, what's up with people. Stop using jQuery as a hammer. This is the right tool for the job.

Comment: +1 This would be the best solution. JavaScript should only be used if there's no server-side access. Even if the divs are to be used only in a js-enabled version, they should be included either way, and styled for either scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you want to do it witout jQuery, it's not that hard:

```
/* Convert a list to an array
 */
function listToArray(list) {
  var result = [],
      i = list.length;
  while (i--) result[i] = list[i];
  return result;
}


/* Wrap elements with tagName in a div until next sibiling
 * with same tagName
 */
function wrapSiblings(tag) {
  tag = tag.toLowerCase();

  // Take elements out of document while processing so
  // need to convert NodeList to array
  var el, els = listToArray(document.getElementsByTagName(tag));
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'chapter';
  var oDiv, oEl;

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    oEl = el.nextSibling;
    oDiv = div.cloneNode(false);

    // Shift all siblings into Div
    while (oEl && !(oEl.tagName && oEl.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag)) {
      oDiv.appendChild(oEl);

      // Moved sibling, get nextSibling - live list!
      oEl = el.nextSibling;
    }

    // Replace el with div, then put el into div
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(oDiv, el);
    oDiv.insertBefore(el, oDiv.firstChild);
  }
}
```